# Multi-OS bootable USB for Mac and Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, mac, usb, multi-boot

At the moment I have two usb's with different linuxes on them , Kali and Ubuntu.
I recently found out that both were taking up little space, which means I could use one usb instyead of two, with extra space for personal

However, I need Kali to be booted on Mac, but when I make one for mac using the Terminal **app**, It creates two small partitions and the rest empty, which I want to put Ubuntu and personal space in.

However the empty space cannot be edited on a mac, nor on windows.

Is there a way to have a Kali Linux for **mac**, Ubuntu for Windows and the rest of the empty space for personal use?

I'm considering to use multi-boot programs such as *YUMI* and *XBoot*, but I'm not sure if they will make Kali bootable on Mac.

I have a 32Gb usb ready for use. Both Linuxes are Live usb, which take up less than 1Gb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, but I didn't test it on a mac!
Before I had made a single OS bootable Kali USB, *which* I had to use Terminal to make it bootable.

However **with [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/), it does this automatically.**